# replace does not replace digits

Tags: java, replace

I want to replace in a string every '0' with a 'F', every '1' with a 'E' and so on.

e.g. "234567890ABCDEF" should result in "DCBA9876543210"

```
            final char[] items = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            newString = oldString.replace(items[i], items[15-i]);
        }
```

unfortunately, this piece of code does not work. It replaces all Letters but not the digits. Any suggestions, why? I'm really at a loss...

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description.  '0' is replaced by '5' in your example, not 'F'

Comment: I'm confused on what you are trying to do here, are you trying to reverse the string? or replace digits? Also please look through some of your questions and accept answers.

Comment: you are seeing FEDCBA9889ABCDEF?

Comment: Is this really the complete code? Strings are immutable in Java, so this could never work this way.

Comment: Aside from issues mentioned by others below, the code you've posted doesn't even do what you claim it does.  Because you override newString on every iteration, the only replacement that will actually stick is the last(replacing 'F' with '0')

Comment: Thank you all very much. I see the problem now, stupid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you replace the digits to letters for i=0 to 7 and back for i=8 to 15.

Comment: Yes though this could some more explanation

Comment: @Mark I tried to keep part of the puzzle while giving a hint as it looks a lot like homework to me.

Comment: What you need is something like Perl's transliteration feature (tr///). However, I don't think there is one built-in to Java. I did see there were a number of implementations of such a library on the web.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you invert the result done during the first eight replacements in your second replacements! This meant,

0-7 are converted back to 0-7, but 8 and 9 will be converted to their conterparts!

Answer (score 0):

If you add debug to your code and look at the iterations you'll notice how you overwrite the results of the first iterations with the replace()es of the last iterations:

```
234567890ABCDEF
23456789FABCDEF
23456789FABCDEF
D3456789FABCDEF
DC456789FABCDEF
DCB56789FABCDEF
DCBA6789FABCDEF
DCBA9789FABCDEF
DCBA9889FABCDEF
DCBA9779FABCDEF
DCBA6776FABCDEF
DCB56776F5BCDEF
DC456776F54CDEF
D3456776F543DEF
23456776F5432EF
23456776F54321F
234567760543210
```